# Getting error "serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/rfcomm0" with pyserial

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pyserial

I want to communicate with my serial port in python. I installed pyserial for linux:

```
import thread
import serial
PORT = '/dev/rfcomm0'
BAUDRATE = 921600
TIMEOUT = 1  
port = serial.Serial(port=PORT, baudrate=BAUDRATE, timeout=TIMEOUT)
port.open()
...
port.close()
```

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dnaphone/PycharmProjects/test/BluetoothClient.py", line 12, in <module>
    port = serial.Serial(port=PORT, baudrate=BAUDRATE, timeout=TIMEOUT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 182, in __init__
    self.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 247, in open
    raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port {}: {}".format(self._port, msg))
serial.serialutil.SerialException: [Errno 2] could not open port /dev/rfcomm0: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/rfcomm0'
```

Comment: it seems to me that is something related to the underlying OS that does not mount /dev/rfcomm0

Comment: run `python -m serial.tools.list_ports` and see if `/dev/rfcomm0` shows up

Comment: @dhdavvie after run is result: no ports found

Comment: @EricMbatchou try with sudo?

Comment: @dhdavvie is the same : no ports found

Comment: @dhdavvie after I do : `sudo rfcomm bind /dev/rfcomm0 98:DD:D0:EA:62:4E 5`,  `/dev/rfcomm0` is shows up. But in file python I have the errors : `[Errno 13] could not open port /dev/rfcomm0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/rfcomm0'`

Comment: @ericmbatchou try running the pythong script with sudo now too, its a permission error

Comment: @dhdavvie thanks ! It's work.

Comment: You can [post an answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to describe the steps and codes you did to make it work. It can be your way of helping others who might experience the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

only you have to do this:

```
sudo chmod 777 /dev/rfcomm0
```

it has already solved